# No fontify in ledger source block

Tags: font-lock, org-mode

I cannot make it show syntax in the org-mode ledger block. It is just shown with plain text. But if I bring it to the edit buffer, it displays the syntax properly. Can anyone help me to trace this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `org-src-fontify-natively` is set to `t`

Comment: I have set it to t. Every other program source block works well.